# How to get results using customize order by query with sparql

Tags: sql-order-by, sparql

If there are some data in .nt data file like :

```
<ted> <pre> <a>.
<alice> <pre> <b>.
<ella> <pre> <c>.
<hens> <pre> <d>.
<lee> <ppp> <other>.
```

I want to order the data by `<pre>` in customize.

The SPARQL query is :

```
//customize order by
select distinct ?s ?o where {
values (?o ?o_){(<a> 1)(<b> 2)}{?s <pre> ?o}
} order by ?o_`
```

The result is

```
<ted> <pre> <a>
<alice> <pre> <b>
```

I want to get all data andI ask if there has wildcard for other data.

```
//(<*> 3) is pseudocode
select distinct ?s ?o where {
values (?o ?o_){(<a> 1)(<b> 2)(<*> 3)}{?s <pre> ?o}
} order by ?o_`
```

Then I can get the data result :

```
<ted> <pre> <a>
<alice> <pre> <b>
<ella> <pre> <c>
<hens> <pre> <d>
<lee> <ppp> <other>
```

Comment: first result:"<ted> <pre> <a> <alice> <pre> <b>". at last result:"<ted> <pre> <a> <alice> <pre> <b> <ella> <pre> <c> <hens> <pre> <d> <lee> <ppp> <other>"

Comment: `values (?o ?o_){(<a> 1)(<b> 2)(UNDEF 3)}`

Comment: thank you very much,that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AKSW commented, solution is to change --

```
values (?o ?o_){(<a> 1)(<b> 2)(<*> 3)}{?s <pre> ?o}
```

-- to --

```
values (?o ?o_){(<a> 1)(<b> 2)(UNDEF 3)}
```

Comment: it can get the result : <ted> <pre> <a>
<alice> <pre> <b>
<ella> <pre> <c>
<hens> <pre> <d>,how can i get the result: <ted> <pre> <a>
<alice> <pre> <b>
<ella> <pre> <c>
<hens> <pre> <d>
<lee> <ppp> <other>

Comment: @cooldream2009 - This and other comments are hard to read. Markdown in the comment is helpful to clarify, but it's better to work the comment (with Markdown!) into your question. As this is written, I cannot see the difference between what you're getting and what you're wanting. It may help if you try to build a similar query against DBpedia or other public SPARQL endpoint, or grant access to your own.

Comment: thank you for your opinion,and i am sorry for my bad expression,i am fresh for stackouverflow.in brief,i want to get the result where ?o is null. (e.g. result should contain <lee> <ppp> <other> ).thank you again,i will try to practise to use markdown.